# What is .numpy() function means and why there is a error here

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras

'numpy.float64' object has no attribute 'numpy'

I found it in this code

```
print("Training Loss:", loss.numpy(), "Validation Acc:",
              accuracy_score(y_true=y_valid, y_pred=y_valid_pred))
```

I cannot find another part about loss, because it is assignment and I need to complete it. full code are belowed. I need to finish "TODO" part

```
# Your code here
def create_network():
  # TODO
  net = tf.keras.Sequential()
  net.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
  net.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'))
  net.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'))
  net.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax'))
  net.compile(tf.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=0.01, momentum=0.0, nesterov=False),
              loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy",
              metrics=["accuracy"])
  #
  return net



def train_network(network,
                  X_train,
                  y_train,
                  X_valid,
                  y_valid,
                  n_epoch=32,
                  batch_size=64):
  n_iter = 0
  opt = tf.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=0.01, momentum=0.0, nesterov=False) #SGD=Stochastic Gradient Descent
  for epoch in range(n_epoch):
    for batch in range(0, X_train.shape[0], batch_size):
      n_iter += 1
      # minibatch data
      X = X_train[batch:batch + batch_size]
      y = y_train[batch:batch + batch_size]

      # TODO
      network.fit(x=X, y=y, epochs=epoch)
      loss, cur=network.evaluate(X,y)                  
      #


      if n_iter % 20 == 0:
        loss, cur=network.evaluate(X,y)
        y_valid_pred = network(X_valid)
        y_valid_pred = np.argmax(y_valid_pred.numpy(), axis=1)
        print("Training Loss:", loss.numpy(), "Validation Acc:",
              accuracy_score(y_true=y_valid, y_pred=y_valid_pred))


net = create_network()
train_network(net, X_train, y_train, X_valid, y_valid)

# evaluate on test set:
y_test_pred = net(X_test)
y_test_pred = np.argmax(y_test_pred.numpy(), axis=1)
print("Test Acc:", accuracy_score(y_true=y_test, y_pred=y_test_pred))
```

Comment: *"I found it in this code..."*  Where did you find that?  How is `loss` created?  It will be much easier for someone to help you if you provide more context.

Comment: Here `.numpy` is being used as method of the `loss` object.  With the right `loss` class it probably creates a new numpy array.  An object generated by `keras/tensorflow` (please edit the tags) may have this method.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser the assignment aim is adding some code and make it run,but I don't know my add code it is right,and  when I run it, it show this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is `loss`?  Look at what produces it:

```
loss, cur=network.evaluate(X,y)
```

and check that method's docs:

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Sequential

`Sequential.evaluate`:

> Returns:
>
> Scalar test loss (if the model has a single output and no metrics) or list of scalars (if the model has multiple outputs and/or metrics). The attribute model.metrics_names will give you the display labels for the scalar outputs.

So `loss` is a scalar, a simple number (technically the error says it's a `numpy.float64').  It doesn't need any conversion to print.

```
print("Training Loss:", loss, "Validation Acc:",...)
```

The use of `numpy()` in the previous line:

```
y_valid_pred.numpy()
```

is valid if `y_valid_pred` is an `tensorflow` object with such a method.  But it shouldn't be used as a model for displaying `loss`.

Comment: loss, cur=network.evaluate(X,y) this one is my answer, maybe it is not true. I mean TODO part need to be completed, and others part have done previously